# Isomorphism of rings under different operations

Tags: ring-theory, abelian-groups

i am new to this site. i have been reading through its posts and question and they are really amazing. however, i found a link to a question asked about one year ago and a question i don't know how to tackle came to my mind. this is the question.

Let R be a ring with a 1. Define R¯ to have the same elements of R with addition ⊕:a⊕b=a+b+1 and multiplication ⊗:a⊗b=ab+a+b Prove that R¯ is isomorphic to R.

how do i go about answering this, because clearly, there is no direct way of proving the conditions for an isomorphism, that is: 
1. f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)
2. f(xy) = f(x)f(y)

i thought about trying to find the inverse of the definition of ⊕ but i couldnt figure out exactly how to get it.

by the way, i have confirmed that both R and R¯ are indeed rings. if i am repeating a certain question or similar question please just provide the link, i guess it might suffice. but so far i haven't found anything close. i have only found trivial examples of isomorphisms. 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the additive identity of $R^-$ is the element that $R$ calls $-1$ and the multiplicative identity is the element that $R$ calls $0$. This suggests that
$$
x \mapsto x-1
$$
will give the desired ring homomorphism $R \to R^-$; this map is clearly bijective.

We check:
$$
x + y \mapsto x + y - 1 = (x-1)\oplus(y-1)
$$

$$
xy \mapsto xy - 1 = (x - 1)(y -1 ) + (x - 1) + (y - 1) = (x-1)\otimes (y-1)
$$

Comment: wow, so how do you decide that x -> x - 1. you have solved it thanks but how did you decide that function. that was the trickiest part it seems. thanks loads though :)))

Answer (score 1):

Before you can prove that $f$ is an isomorphism, you need to discover what $f$ *is*. But once you have the right function, the verification is actually straightforward.

**Hint.** Clearly $f$ needs to be defined in a way that doesn't depend on which particular ring $R$ is. Pretty much the only way you can construct a function that will make sense for *every* ring in the same way is a polynomial. Can you find a polynomial that satisfies $f(x)\oplus f(y)=f(x+y)$?

Comment: ahh that also occured to me, but when i couldn't exactly figure out such a function i thought there might be another way to approach the problem, that is why i consulted you. thanks though :)